# Qt: QListView change behaviour of MultiSelection selection mode

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

I have QListView with MultiSelection option for selecting items.

```
listView->setSelectionMode(MultiSelection);
```

It is exactly what I want except one thing. I don't want a deselect behaviour on drag select(When I'm dragging over selected items they become unselected). I want items below drag selection to be always selected.

Is there a way to change this behaviour?

UPDATE: Wrapping is enabled so items are drawn in a couple of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the selection behaviour of the QListView you should re-implement `QAbstractItemView::selectionCommand` function. Here is an example:

mylistwidget.h

```
#ifndef MYLISTWIDGET_H
#define MYLISTWIDGET_H

#include <QListWidget>
#include <QItemSelectionModel>

class MyListWidget : public QListWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyListWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    virtual QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags selectionCommand(const QModelIndex &index,
                                                                 const QEvent *event = 0) const;
};

#endif // MYLISTWIDGET_H
```

mylistwidget.cpp

```
MyListWidget::MyListWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QListWidget(parent)
{
}

QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags MyListWidget::selectionCommand(const QModelIndex & index, const QEvent * event) const
{
    QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags flags = QAbstractItemView::selectionCommand(index, event);

    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        flags &= ~QItemSelectionModel::Toggle;
        flags |= QItemSelectionModel::Select;
    }

    return flags;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that wrapping is enabled so items are drawn in a couple of lines. But I'm not sure this will work either, because this solutions select item directly above cursor, and when cursor moves to the next item selected item would be unselected once again.

Comment: Do you mean the `wordWrap`? Because this works with `wordWrap=true`. 

Previous item won't be un-selected if you enable multi selection with `listWidget->setSelectionMode(MultiSelection);`. I should have add this to the code.

Comment: No I meant: listView->setWrapping(true);

Comment: So you are using QListView in `IconMode`?

Comment: Yes. These are my QListView adjustments:    
    setDragDropMode(DragDrop);
    setSelectionMode(MultiSelection);
    setMovement(Free);
    setFlow(LeftToRight);
    setWrapping(true);
    setResizeMode(Adjust);
    setViewMode(IconMode);
    setSelectionRectVisible(true);
    setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);

Comment: Ohh you mean selecting with the "selection rectangle"? I thought you were trying to select items by dragging over them which is default behaviour in ListMode. Let me take a look at that.

Comment: I've updated my answer. This is a better solution which allows easily tweaking the selection behavior according to current event (for example you can check if Ctrl is pressed) and items that are to be selected. Also it works with rectangle selection.